# What are the risks of running a database on a server without ECC RAM?

Tags: mysql, hardware, memory, dell, ecc

A lot of branded servers come with ECC RAM, but it is expensive.

For a database server or other critical servers, what would be the impact of **not** using ECC RAM?

Data corruption? (I suppose the database software should handle this already, right?)
So why would I need ECC RAM?

Comment: This has been discussed quite a lot already.  See, for example: http://serverfault.com/questions/5887/what-is-ecc-ram-and-why-is-it-better

Comment: unfortunately, these answers are simply wrong. Database's ACID does not require ECC RAM.

Comment: @Howard - However, a bit error on a cached data block can get written out to disk with that bit error, which then persists the bit error for all eternity.  The DBMS may or may not have a checksum on individual blocks, but it doesn't calculate and store error correcting codes on the pages - at least none that I'm aware of do this.  A bit error on an index block could be really dire.

Comment: For MySQL (InnoDB), a flipping bit causes a 16KB page checksum to be invalid. Because MySQL just dies encountering such errors in index or data, it will enter a restart loop, crashing again whenever the block is encountered again. You may start in a recovery mode and try to dump all data, hoping it was an index page, but it's risky because data may be corrupt. Put simply: A bit flip in InnoDB data means restore from backup. All of it. Happened to me last week - easy to replace slave DB. Non-ECC RAM is a very bad idea for databases, and a bad idea in general, also desktops with current sizes.